# The login page keeps reloading on the authenticated page in Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm adding spring security to my spring boot web project. It's okay when go to allow page, retristed page. But in needed authentication page, after submit the login page keeps reloading.

I suspect something is wrong when doing the authenticate. I read the log file but no help. The `failureUrl("/login?error=true")` does not raise anything.

What is wrong with my code?

Here the pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the security config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
 
    @Autowired 
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
                        authorize.requestMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/index").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/brand","/shop").hasRole("ADMIN")
                ).formLogin(
                        form -> form
                                .loginPage("/login")
                               // .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
                                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                                .permitAll()
                ).logout(
                        logout -> logout
                                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/checkout"))
                                .permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
 
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/image/**", "/js/**","/css/**");
    }
```

The users class

```
public class Users {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int user_id;

private String user_name ="anonymous";
private String password;
private Long phone = 12345L;
private String gender = "male";
private String email;
public String main_image = "1.jpeg";
private Date created_date;

private String main_address;
private boolean enabled;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
        )
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();}
```

The role class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int role_id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
    private List<Users> users;
      
}
```

Here is the UserDetailServiceImpl

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UsersRepository UsersRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) 
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Users user = UsersRepository.getUserByUsername(username);
    
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user");
    }
    else{
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUser_name(),
                user.getPassword(),
                mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
    }       
}

private Collection < ? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection <Role> roles) {
    Collection < ? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRoles = roles.stream()
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return mapRoles;
}}
```

Here is the log file

```
Securing POST /shop2023-03-31T19:38:50.289+07:00 DEBUG 12560 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymousSecurityContext
2023-03-31T19:38:50.294+07:00 DEBUG 12560 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/shop?continue to session2023-03-31T19:38:50.298+07:00 DEBUG 12560 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy : Redirecting tohttp://localhost:8080/login 
2023-03-31T19:38:50.459+07:00 DEBUG 12560 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-03-31T19:38:50.608+07:00 DEBUG 12560 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-03-31T19:38:51.094+07:00 DEBUG 12560 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, delete the Login post mapping method because spring security will handle that, no need for us to do this.

Second, add `action=login` and `th:post` to thymelef login page:

```
<form action="login" th:method="post">
```

Third, add `name=username` and `name=password` for the input:

```
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
```

Here is the SecurityFilterChain that works for me:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
                    authorize.requestMatchers("/index","/error").permitAll()
                             .requestMatchers("/shop").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ).formLogin(
                    form -> form
                            .loginPage("/login")
                            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
                            .usernameParameter("username")
                            .passwordParameter("password")
                            .permitAll()
            ).logout(
                    logout -> logout
                            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/checkout"))
                            .permitAll()
            );
    return http.build();
}
```